# Is there any performance penalty with using INSERT OR REPLACE followed by a SELECT?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables the PhraseId is the primary key in both and Modified is the number of seconds since 1970. Modified is part of the data load but not required unless it makes the updating easier. If I can do without it then I would just like to use the INSERT OR REPLACE

```
PhraseSource with columns PhraseId, Text, Modified
Phrase       with columns PhraseId, Text, Modified
```

The PhraseSource table contains 5010 rows (some new and some changed rows)
The Phrase table contains 5000 rows. I would like to update the Phrase table with the new and changed rows from PhraseSource. Note that my application doesn't need to show the modified data but it was added in case it could make it easier to do the inserting or updating.

Here's what I came up with. Can you let me know if this is a good way to do the update and insert.

```
 INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Phrase(PhraseId, Text)
 SELECT PS.PhraseId, PS.text FROM PhraseSource AS PS
```

If there's a better way to do this (perhaps using the modifed column that contains number of seconds since 1970 when the row was last modified at the source) then I would also very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: REPLACE just deletes the old row if there is a conflict,so it rewrites the entire table even if there aren't many actual changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5000 rows is nothing; you could just delete and copy the entire table.

If you want to minimize the amount of changes that are written, this can be easily done with the `Modified` column: first delete all rows that are older, then copy over all new rows:

```
DELETE FROM Phrase
WHERE Modified < (SELECT Modified
                  FROM PhraseSource
                  WHERE PhraseId = Phrase.PhraseId);

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Phrase(PhraseId, Text, Modified)
SELECT PhraseId, Text, Modified FROM PhraseSource;
```

Without `Modified`, the same can be done by comparing the actual values:

```
DELETE FROM Phrase
WHERE Text IS NOT (SELECT Text
                   FROM PhraseSource
                   WHERE PhraseId = Phrase.PhraseId);

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Phrase(PhraseId, Text)
SELECT PhraseId, Text FROM PhraseSource;
```